# How to add kio-gdrive in debian

Tags: debian, networking, kde, google-drive

I'm new to Debian. I'm using KDE plasma in Debian. In Dolphin there is no gdrive folder. Before this I was using Kubuntu. I saw the default G-drive access. But here its not available.

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.
And also I would like to use the google photos like googleDrive. Is it possible in dolphin?

Answer (score 1):

Install [`kio-gdrive`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/kio-gdrive) package:

> KIO GDrive enables KIO-aware applications (such as Dolphin, Kate or Gwenview) to access and edit Google Drive files in the cloud.

```
sudo apt install kio-gdrive
```

Package available for debian Buster and  bullseye.

Comment: Is there anything like Google photos same as G-drive?

Comment: This worked/ But same problem which i faced in Kubuntu.